# having trouble comparison counting while in binary search and sequential, need clarity

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

I have a quick quick question but I am having trouble understanding, code sample below with commented documentation.

When searching through an array of elements using binarySearch what is considering a comparison?

or in the case of `int` array containing `178,384,471,478,487,576,617,630,649,817,821,915,917,972,975` with `821` being the target what would the comparison count be???

I have posted where I think comparisons take place, please correct me if I'm wrong, or tell me if I'm right please :) thanks all.

```
public static int binarySearch(String[] data, String target, int first, int last)
{
  if(first > last)
     return -1;
  else
    int middle = (first+last)/2;
    int result = data[first].compareTo(data[middle])
    if(result == 0) //IS THIS A COMPARISON? (I THINK YES)
      return middle;
    else if(result < 0) // IS THIS A COMPARISON (I THINK YES)
      return binarySearch(data,target.first,middle-1);
    else
      return binarySearch(data,target,middle+1,last); // IS THIS A COMPARISON? (I THINK NO)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is real comparison  `int result = data[first].compareTo(data[middle])` the if-statements only do different things based on the "real" comparison.

Comment: well how many times would that be calulated in an `int` array containing `178,384,471,478,487,576,617,630,649,817,821,915,917,972,975` with `821` being the target.

Comment: you can add print statement `System.out.println("executed")` after/before the comparison line. Then count the lines in the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

So, almost by definition, any [equality or relational operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) or method that wraps such an operator would be a comparison.

In general, what you probably want to assess is the order of your algorithms as the input grows, it is enough to count say times that the function gets called, even if inside there are 3 comparisons for instance. The order (in this case O(log(n)) will not change.

Side notes: you might want to use a actual array of integers instead of string comparison, which can be costly AND tricky (i.e. "12" > "110"). Also, it would eliminate the need to get a "result", just do comparison against the stored values.

Comment: Yea sorry I just wanted to provide both  string example and integer. Ok can you try and break that first and second paragraph down a little for me..if possible. im rusty on my bigO stuff

Comment: Answer me something first: why exactly do you need to know what is a comparison? I have a guess but I can probably give you a better answer with a little more context. What is you final goal here?

Comment: so when given an array and a target to search for, I have to count the number of comparisons (just on paper) and provide how many comparisons it took from that array to the target. this has to be done for both sequential and binary search. just on paper.

Comment: Well, that does not quite answer me "why?". If you want to know how many comparisons occur, the answer is different for strings than for integers. An integer comparison translates into a single machine comparison. A string comparison transforms into an iteration over each character in the string, potentially up to the size of the smallest one. Thus, many more comparisons. Other than that, your comments are accurate, you are just missing the method calls.